# Check whether an object/function is defined (JavaScript, Safari issue)

Tags: javascript, safari

I would like to check whether I can use an object/function, for example `window.performance.now()`. `if(typeof window.performance.now != 'undefined')` works fine, except for Safari (5.1.7, Windows), which returns `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.performance.now')`. To avoid confusion: `console.log(typeof window.performance.now)` returns the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `window.performance` object itself is not supported in Safari. So you'd be safer checking for

```
typeof window.performance !== 'undefined' && typeof window.performance.now !== 'undefined'
```

**Update**

The first check is to see if the `window.performance` object exists. The second check is to see if the `.now()` function is available in the `window.performance` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance

Comment: Thanks. The bad thing is, that `.now()` also needs to be checked after this.

Comment: Yes, it'd be safe to check for both the availability of the object and the availability of the function. The only cases where you'll get the availability of the object and no support for the `now()` function is for IE9 and Opera 15 though - according to the link I provided.

Comment: Is there any version of any browser/JS, which evaluates `b` in `if(a && b)`, assuming that `a` is `false`?

Comment: If you're using `&&` it must check both conditions. **Edit** If you use `||` it'll only check `b` if `a` is not satisfied. So the OR operand would still not work if `performance` is not available.

Comment: "If you're using && it must check both conditions." - this statement is incorrect.

Comment: @ee735ee please explain.. **Update** no wait I see it, if `a` is false it'll return false without even checking `b`. You're right, I stand corrected - same with `||` if `a` is true then `b` is not checked. I need to refresh my logical thinking, obviously..

Comment: Yes, my question was is it safe to assume, that `b` is never (any browser/JS version) evaluated, when `a` is `false`. But I guess I would have to create another question for this.

Comment: Based on our discussion the answer is yes, it is safe to assume `b` will not be evaluated. And so the answer should be edited to `typeof window.performance !== 'undefined' && typeof window.performance.now !== 'undefined'`

Comment: My only concern about this, there might be some old browsers, like IE6 (I can't test it), which aren't smart enough to skip the evaluation of `b`.

Comment: That's a fair concern, given IE's drawbacks. I can't answer this for certain as I don't have any means of testing on old browsers as well. It might be best to start a new topic regarding this, I'd be interested to know if others have insight into it.